# Javascript adding 2nd dimension not returning results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a site made as shown in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bAz3y/

```
$.getJSON('eventbrite.json', function(data) {
    var events = [];
    var j = 0;

    for (var i in data) {
        events[i][0] = data[i].event.title;
    }

    $('.btn-lg').click(function() {
        $('#tester').replaceWith("<div id='tester'>" + events[j][0] + "</div>");
        j = j + 1;
    })
    $("div.swiper").on("swipe",function() {
        $('#tester').replaceWith("<div id='tester'>" + events[j][0] + "</div>");
        j = j + 1;
    })
});
```

I'm trying to get the 2nd dimension to store the event title, so that I can then add event date and distance in `events[j][1]` and `events[j][2]`.

However, adding the second dimension (ie the `events[i][0]`) means no results are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `for` loop, `events[i]` is undefined so `events[i][0]` will fail

1.Solution is

```
for (var i in data) {
    events[i] = [data[i].event.title, data[i].event.some];
}
```

2.Another is to use $.each() and do

```
var events = [];
var j = 0;

$.each(data, function(_,item){
    events.push([item.event.title, data[i].event.some])
});
```

3.A third way is to use $.map()

```
var j = 0;

var events = $.map(data, function (item) {
    return [[item.event.title, data[i].event.some]]
});
```

Comment: Using the top suggestion, events[i] works, but using events[i][0] does not.

Comment: @user3057706 it is creating a two dimensional array.. after the for loop try `events[0][0]` not inside